# Basis smaller than a topology

Tags: general-topology

If $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\tau= \{X, \phi, \{1\}\}$, is there a basis for this that is not the topology itself?

Comment: $\{X,\{1\}\}$ forms a basis, no? To get the empty set you take the empty union

Comment: I'm just going off the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)

Comment: The answer depends on whether the notion of an empty union is allowed. The answer is NO if empty unions are not allowed (under this assumption, each of the three 2-element subsets of $\tau$ is easily seen to not be a basis; hence, none of the singleton subsets can be a basis, and of course $\emptyset$ is not a basis) and YES if empty unions are allowed (as @Michael Morrow has shown).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro empty unions are irrelevant, if the definition of base is $\forall O \in \mathcal{T}:\forall x \in O: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: x \in B \subseteq O$, as is also common.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: This reminds me of a class discussion I and a few others, along with [our teacher](https://people.math.sc.edu/nyikos/), had in a Spring 1987 topology class. I believe it had to do with the "empty topological space" (the underlying set is $\emptyset$ and the topology is $\{\emptyset\})$ and the "empty metric space" (the underlying set is $\emptyset$ and the distance function is $\emptyset),$ each of which I believe was allowed (but not explicitly mentioned) in our text, Willard's *General Topology* --- which theorems in Willard might require the space to be nonempty?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Nyikos, great topologist IMO.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Totally awesome in teaching also, at least in the two graduate topology classes I had with him. His lectures were excellent with regard to logical detail and pace, so pretty much anyone remotely qualified for the class could follow along, and he gave numerous tangents involving tweaking or weakening various hypotheses (my copy of Willard is full of such tweaks and minor theorem strengthenings), so better students could "own the subject" and also get a sense of how one might begin researching some mathematical topic.

Answer (score 2):

In any space $\mathcal{B}:=\mathcal{T}\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ is a base unequal to the topology. Also here.

$\{\{1\}\}$ is a subbase for the topology (the topology is the smallest one that contains this subbase).